# Standardize phone numbers in submitted form with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, phone-number, cfml

We're looking for a way to standardize the entry of phone numbers entered in a form to be, for example, (444) 555-666. Right now you can enter it as any format, such as 4445556666 or 444-555-6666 and there's no standardization. I'd like a way for the number to be converted to the former format when it's entered into the database.

Here is the HTML code for the form:

```
<tr>
  <td align="right">
    <label for="phone_number">Telephone:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" value="#form.phone_number#" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

This, along with all other data, is entered into the database using a cfquery INSERT INTO command. I can provide that code if needed. Here's an abbridged version:

```
INSERT INTO Schedule_Registrations(
  phone_number
)
VALUES(
  '#FORM.phone_number#'
)
```

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You should really be using cfqueryparam.  Never insert user-accessible data directly into a query.  You are risking a sql injection attack. Replace '#form.phone_number#' with <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.phone_number#" />

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way I've chosen to deal with this issue is to store raw numbers in the database, and then display them how I want on a web page. To normalize the numbers, use a simple regex:

```
<cfset cleanPhoneNumber = reReplace(form.phoneNumber, "[^0-9]", "", "ALL")>
```

Store cleanPhoneNumber in the database, and then use a simple format function to display it:

```
<cffunction name="formatPhoneNumber">
    <cfargument name="phoneNumber" required="true">

    <cfif len(phoneNumber) EQ 10>
        <!--- This only works with 10-digit US/Canada phone numbers --->
        <cfreturn "(#left(phoneNumber, 3)#) #mid(phoneNumber, 4, 3)#-#right(phoneNumber, 4)#">
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn phoneNumber>
</cffunction>
```

The challenge is that outside the US there is not a standardized way to format numbers (that I've found). Also be careful if you allow a user to enter an extension in the phone number field.

Comment: I would add, don't clean the number before putting into the DB, clean it when you display it to yourself or others. That way you always have the option to show them what they entered.

Comment: I store both the phone number as entered and a cleaned up version. I have an index in the DB on the cleaned version so i can search by phone number a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

I liked Scott's approach. So I combined it and made a function for `<cfscript>`

```
string function formatPhone(required string phoneNumber) output="false"    {

    arguments.phoneNumber = reReplace(arguments.phoneNumber, "[^0-9]", "", "ALL");

    if (len(arguments.phoneNumber) == 10)   {
        return "(#left(arguments.phoneNumber, 3)#) #mid(arguments.phoneNumber, 4, 3)#-#right(arguments.phoneNumber, 4)#";
      }

    return arguments.phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: if you change the regex to `[^0-9]|^\+1(?=\d{10})$`, you can also deal with leading a leading `1` or `+1` in one operation, which is sometimes how people try to enter phone numbers.